# Main Module is missing and I don't know why?

Tags: python, pycharm

Everytime I got the error that the `Main Module` is missing:

> C:\Users\G.A\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in 'C:/Users/MA/PycharmProjects'

So then I go to the configuration edit and add a main module but then I get the below error after the following command:

```
usage: venv [-h] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--clear]
        [--upgrade] [--without-pip] [--prompt PROMPT]
        ENV_DIR [ENV_DIR ...]
```

Error:

> venv: error: the following arguments are required: ENV_DIR

So I go again to the configuration and add a script path. Then I get the error that the main module is again missing. It's like a vicious cycle. 
What should I do?

I downloaded Python from Anaconda and Pycharm from Jetbrains.

Comment: Please, show how you run your python program

Comment: Are you trying to run a package instead of a script?

Comment: OH jeez! Yeah, that was my fault. Problem fixed.